# Trouble getting to an explicit solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the ODE:

$(y^2-1)\frac{dy}{dx} =4xy^2$

I can get to an implicit solution easily enough:

$y+\frac{1}{y} = 2x^2$+c.

However, I've been given an explicit solution:

$y(x)=x^2-c_2\pm\sqrt{(c_2-x^2)^2-1}$

and I can't figure out how to get there.  I'm teaching myself ODEs so there's a very good chance that there is some obvious algebraic manipulation trick that I'm missing. I've been wracking my brains for hours over this so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation has the form
$$
y+ y^{-1}= f(x)
$$Multiply by $y$, isolate, and use the quadratic formula:
$$
y^2 - f(x)\cdot y + 1 = 0
$$
$$
y = \frac{f(x) \pm \sqrt{f(x)^2-4}}{2}
$$

Comment: Thanks very much.  I knew there was a trick.